# Difference between VGA compatible controller and 3D controller

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

Why is it that I don't see my NVIDIA graphic adapter under VGA compatible controller but under 3D controller when I use `lspci -vnn`? What's the difference between the two and under which section should it actually be?

Edit : Output Of lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0662
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GeForce 820M
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Just edited as you asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the adapter firmware how it declares itself to PCI bus.

Some Nvidia laptop adapters declare themselves as a `3D controller`.

That does not make any practical difference.

The reason for that is probably because in an Optimus dual graphics systems, the Nvidia chip is not a real adapter. It outputs through the Intel adapter anyway and does only hardware acceleration.

You can install a proprietary driver in System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers (nvidia-352), or in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Both methods do the same. This will install the stable recommended driver.

If you need "the latest" drivers, you can install them by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
```

at your own risk.

Comment: http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04 describes the process of installing latest nvidia drivers for ubuntu. Would it work if my adapter describes itseld as 3D controller?

Comment: Driver installation is the same. But the manual is outdated and will not work. `xorg-edgers` does not contain Nvidia drivers now. Why not install recommended driver from Ubuntu repositories a normal way.

Comment: Err.. I have no idea how to go that normal way. I searched google and that was the first result I found. Mind telling me about it?

Comment: Go to System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers and select a driver there.

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't seem to work. For last many months, even after updating and upgrading my system,  `Additional Drivers` continues to show the same version and I doubt if they're the latest version.

Comment: Which is that version? What is the Ubuntu version? And why you need "the latest" drivers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35686/discussion-between-7-r3x-and-pilot6).